# A word that describes "a song that is not easy to get tired of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Chinese there is a word called "耐聽" to describe a song that you can listen to for a million times and you wouldn't get tired or sick of it. Is there an English word suits this description? Example sentence would be **"This song is ______. I can never get tired of it."**

Some songs have beautiful melodies and you enjoy them at first. But only after a while you found that you've had enough of them and you do not enjoy these songs any more. You would say **"The song sounds great at first. But it is not ______. I don't love it anymore. In fact, I feel sick of it now."**

Answer (score 3):

I would opt for the short phrase "**never gets old**". This is what [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=never%20gets%20old) has for a definition and example:

> I will never get tired or bored of this.
>
> > The spoof music video "Pop goes my heart" from Music and Lyrics "never gets old" for me. I could watch it again and again.

This is said very often of songs (though not exclusively of them).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's exact word in English for the Chinese word but you could say *an evergreen or a catchy song*.

There's also *mellifluous, harmonious, melodious* which describe a tuneful and pleasant song.

*Timeless* would also work (*a timeless song*).

There's also *[earworm](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/earworm)* which means *a tune or part of a song that repeats in one’s mind*, but it has negative connotations.

> **Evergreen (adj):** Always seeming fresh or remaining popular.
>
> Example: That evergreen TV series "Friends".
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evergreen)

> **Catchy (adj):** (especially of a tune or song) pleasing and easy to remember.
>
> Examples:
>
> - a catchy tune
> - a song with catchy lyrics
> - a catchy name/slogan
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catchy)

> **Timeless (adj):** Having a value that is not limited to a particular period but will last for ever.
>
> Example: a timeless book/play/film/classic
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/timeless)

Comment: They're [more common as a collocation,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catchy+songs%2Ctimeless+songs&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatchy%20songs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctimeless%20songs%3B%2Cc0) but if anything, I'd say ***catchy** songs* are more likely to be ephemeral (here today, gone tomorrow), compared to ***timeless** songs*. And that's not least because *catchy **tunes*** are even more common, but "tunes" are definitely more ephemeral than "songs".

Comment: I think __*timeless*__ and __*evergreen*__ are the closest by far.

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation of "耐聽" would be "I am able to bear the sound without resistance."

Translated, it is very poetic and almost romantic towards 'the sound'.

It would be a line that, to my knowledge, would come from Shakespeare himself.

*Words* in Chinese often come out to be *phrases* in English.

So the term you're looking for and/or to best translate, I would agree with existing answers and add,

"I [could] listen to this song on repeat." "[This sounds] lives rent free in my head."